# Flask: How to run a method before every route in a blueprint?

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I want to make my Flask Blueprint always run a method before executing any routes. Instead of decorating every route method in my blueprint with a custom decorator, I want to be able to do something like this:

```python
def my_method():
    do_stuff

section = Blueprint('section', __name__)

# Register my_method() as a setup method that runs before all routes
section.custom_setup_method(my_method())

@section.route('/two')
def route_one():
    do_stuff

@section.route('/one')
def route_two():
    do_stuff
```

Then basically both `/section/one` and `/section/two` will run `my_method()` before executing code in `route_one()` or `route_two()`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [before_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_request) decorator for blueprints. Like this:

```
@section.before_request
def my_method():
    do_stuff
```

This automatically registers the function to run before any routes that belong to the blueprint.

Comment: Why not just write your function as a decorator in the first place?

Comment: @SamRedway that works but then you have to add a decorator to every route. If you use the `before_request()` decorator at the app or blueprint level, you just have to specify it once.

Comment: Updated link to [before_request docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_request)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `before_request` for this:

```
@section.before_request
def before_request():
    do_stuff
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request